# Non static class used in another class <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, class, static

I'm struggling with using a non static function from one class inside another class. I've been reading some examples, but having a hard time understanding the basics of it. My best try so far, was by using the example given from http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html#static

I have two classes: ledStrips and MPTimers. MPTimers is a class to use timers on an Atmega. What I want, is to be able to call an instance of MPTimers within ledStrips. In the class of MPTimers, I can attach a callback function, which will be run each time the timer interrupts.

Here's an example of my code, only showing what's relevant.

```
MPTimers _timerOne;

// Constructor
ledStrips::ledStrips()
{
_timerOne.initialize(1000); // Set up timer with 1000 ms delay
_timerOne.attachFunction(timeout); // Attach a function to the timer
_timerOne.stop(); // Stop timer
}
```

The timeout function, which is the parameter in .attachFunction, is a member of ledStrips.

This is the code in MPTimers class

```
// AttachFunction
void MPTimers::attachFunction(void (*isr)() )
{
isrCallBack = isr;
}
```

And the error is:
error: no matching function for call to 'MPTimers::attachFunction(unresolved overloaded function type).

I know it's because my instance of MPTimers have no idea to know, which instance the callback function is referering to, because it's a non static member of the class.

I tried the solution as described in the link, but with no succes. Hope that some of you can help me to figure this out :).

Comment: Does `timeout` have the matching signature (`void timeout()`)? As I understood you'll need this function to declare as `static void timeout();` member in your `ledStrips` class.

Comment: Yes it is declared as a void timeout with the same signature :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a functer on a non-static member function, the syntax would be

```
void MPTimers::attachFunction(void (MPTimers::*isr)() )
{
isrCallBack = isr;
}
```

and if you want to call it later the syntax would be

```
{
[....]
this->*isrCallback()
[....]
}
```

Comment: Just to get this straight. I.e. in my interrupt ISR routine, which calls the Isrcallback(), it should be chaned grom isrCallBack () to this->*isrCallBack().

In my other class, I should then be able to call the attachFunction(timeout) without any problems? Or is there any syntax I should be aware of?

And thanks for the answer :)

Comment: sorry but it seem that i don't understand your code so well><. Is `void timeout()` a _fonction_, a _methode_ or a _static methode_?. and by there if it's a _methode/function_. where did you defined it?

Comment: It is a function inside my ledStrips class.

The idea is that every time I get a timeout from my Timer class, I have to call the timeout function inside ledStrips, which clears/set some registers.

Comment: So if i'm right you store a methode functer from ledStrips inside a MPTimers Object... wich you use later in a LEDstrip methode?

Comment: i thinks that's the code you want? _http://ideone.com/mIAabj_. wich i done in it is attach the callback Methode wich is inside the LDStrip class, and then re-use this methode functer later by getting it from the MPTimers... is it ok? or is this not what you wanted?

Comment: So what it would d, is that from my ledStrip class i can attach a function from my ledStrip class as a callback into my MPTimers class, which will run the function? 

Thanks so much for the code, but there's one thing bugging me. It appears that it's all written in a main file? I would like my MPTimers class to be independant of any other class. From I get, the MPTimers class needs to include the ledStrips.h header, (typedef void LEDStrips::*LEDStripsCallBack), or am I just completely lost here ? :)

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit unclear about all this. I'm very new to the use of callback methods in different classes.

Comment: **MPTimers** can't be totally independant from **LEDStrips**, beacause, in facts a methode functer would need it's context (`this`) as see in `this->*_c`... and i'm a bit lost there (my bad english limit me in the understanding of wich you want ><)... so i think it would be good for you if you look a bit to the link that @Javier S. gave you!

Comment: But really appreciate the help you been given me CollioTV :) Will try to get a better fundamental understand of the callbacks from the link Javier posted

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a non-static method of a class without an object instanced from that class. MPTimers::attachFunction expects a static method or function. If your timeout function is a normal C function then there should be no problem (so it's obviously not the case), if it is a static method of a class then you should use ClassName::timeout, if it's a non-static method of a class then you can't do what you want, you'll need to modify your attachFunction and your MPTimers class to accept functors or object/method pairs (or use a static timeout method).

Comment: I guess the easiest solution is to change my MPTimers class to accept functors.

A valid solution would then be to try CollioTV's answer ? :)

Comment: CollioTV's solution would work ONLY if you're using an MPTimer method as a callback. If your callback is a method in another class (say, ClassA), then you'll have to pass a ClassA instance and a ClassA method, and then invoke the callback like this:
(obj->*method)(). You can see the different possibilities here: http://www.tutok.sk/fastgl/callback.html

Comment: Thanks Javier. Definitely going to look into that :)